# SpringBoot handle validation exceptions from API and JPA layer differently

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I came upon a problem with validation exceptions on different layers.

If there is validation exception on Controller level (for example parameter has @Min value), Spring throws ConstraintViolationException. Since this is User fault, I map this to HTTP 400 error response.

But the same error is thrown by JPA on flushing entity if it has some constraints on entity fields. In this case, I cannot send 400 to user, since this is server fault and in many cases, these fields have nothing to do with data from user (they might, but not directly).

Is there a way to automatically wrap all exceptions from JPA level, so that ConstraintViolationException from controller (and possibly facade level) are not mixed with ConstraintViolationException from Hibernate/JPA level? Preferably for SpringBoot version 2.7.*

Thanks!

Comment: Your service layer should **not allow** such faulty data to reach the database layer in first place.

Comment: Apart for strongly agreeing with @Chaosfire comment, I suggest you to have a look at [ExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc/#using-exceptionhandler) where you can catch the type of exception you want and return the appropriate error response.

Comment: You should define & use your own error code like ERROR-ABC123.

Comment: @Chaosfire - and how to do that? Imagine this scenario - user posts a form, which is valid. Based on these data I retrieve data from 3rd party system. I compute some string based on retrieve objects and this string exceeds the limit for 1000 characters and the exception is thrown. If I dont handle this at all, I get JDBC exception for column length (which doesnt event contain column name). If i annotate the entity field I get ConstraintViolation exception (current situation). The third solution is to handle this imperatively. And it is not possible to handle all potential situations.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ - I am doing that. But my problem is that, both validation error on Controller level and on JPA level throw the same type. And I need to handle them differently. I could check the stack trace, to make the decision, but I would rather use some built-in logic in SpringBoot, to wrap exception from JPA layer, so I can differentiate based on class.

Comment: @Nooras Fatima Ansari - not sure what you mean. If you mean adding additional information to exception thrown from JPA, I would need to add catch to every DB call (which is not even possible when using declarative transactions). And if i could do that, I could already wrap the exception to other type to solve my issue without introducing error codes.

Comment: @Gobanit It's not the cleanest solution (it's still better than letting db layer throw exception IMO), but you can write custom validator for those cases and instead of returning false throw a custom exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go this way. To decide if the constraint violation comes from Controller or JPA layer, I check the validated object found in the exception. In case of request parameters, this would be the Controller instance itself and I can distinguish those by checking if the class has @RestController annotation. Without probing the stackTrace.

I could also go the other way around and check if the validated class is an @Entity. But this way seems more defensive, because I rather throw 500 in case of user error, than 400 in case of server error.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException::class)
fun handleValidationException(
  ex: ConstraintViolationException,
  response: HttpServletResponse
): ResponseEntity<ApiExceptionDto> {
  if (isControllerLevelValidationException(ex)) return createApiExceptionResponse(ex.localizedMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  logger.error("Unhandled internal error", ex);
  return createApiExceptionResponse("Internal Error", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
}


private fun isControllerLevelValidationException(e: ConstraintViolationException): Boolean {
  val violations = e.constraintViolations
  for (violation in violations) {
    val rootBeanClass = violation.rootBeanClass
    if (!rootBeanClass.isAnnotationPresent(RestController::class.java)) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as @Chaosfire said "Your service layer should not allow such faulty data to reach the database layer in first place." but
if you insist doing that, you can do it like below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        if (isControllerException(e)) {
        
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Bad Request: " + e.getMessage());
        } else {
       
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private boolean isControllerException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement element : stackTrace) {
            // Check if the class name contains "controller" (case insensitive)
            if (element.getClassName().toLowerCase().contains("controller")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this would not work, since any stack trace in app, that is not scheduled task would contain Controller class somewhere at the stack bottom. But yeah, this is the one way to go, if I know what to look for in stack trace (for example some classes from lower levels, like Repositories)